# Flink: Sharing state in CoFlatMapFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Got stuck a bit with `CoFlatMapFunction`. It seems to work fine if I place it on the `DataStream` before window but fails if placed after window's “apply” function.

I was testing two streams, main “Features” on `flatMap1` constantly ingesting data and control stream “Model” on `flatMap2` changing the model on request.

I am able to set and see b0/b1 properly set in `flatMap2`, but `flatMap1` always see b0 and b1 as was set to 0 at the initialization.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```java
public static class applyModel implements CoFlatMapFunction<Features, Model, EnrichedFeatures> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Double b0;
    Double b1;

    public applyModel(){
        b0=0.0;
        b1=0.0;
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Features value, Collector<EnrichedFeatures> out) {
        System.out.print("Main: " + this + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(Model value, Collector<EnrichedFeatures> out) {
        System.out.print("Old Model: " + this + "\n");
        b0 = value.getB0();
        b1 = value.getB1();
        System.out.print("New Model: " + this + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "CoFlatMapFunction: {b0: " + b0 + ", b1: " + b1 + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do in the in the window `apply` function? Maybe you can share the respective code with us.

Comment: for (Raw value: values) {
            if(value.getTs() > end_ts) end_ts = value.getTs();
            if (value.getTs() < start_ts) start_ts = value.getTs();

            if(last_event_ts == 0L){
                last_event_ts = value.getTs();
            } else {
                dwell_time += value.getTs() - last_event_ts;
                last_event_ts = value.getTs();
            }
        }

        out.collect(new Features(tuple.getField(0), tuple.getField(2), tuple.getField(1), start_ts, end_ts, size, dwell_time, Boolean.FALSE));

Comment: I'll check whether I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Parallel instances was my issue. Had to make sure that both streams are keyed the same way of set parallelism of my CoFlatMapFunction to 1. Thanks to Stephan Ewen

[MORE INFORMATION](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201511.mbox/%3CCANC1h_uJirMZT4EK7pKYLg_xih0u0RgQ6qJTrAnxu0eLcZw-VA%40mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: Great to hear. Do you want to post Stephan's answer here so that others with the same problem can easily spot the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer from the mailing list...

> Is the CoFlatMapFunction intended to be executed in parallel?
>
> If yes, you need some way to deterministically assign which record
>   goes to which parallel instance. In some way the CoFlatMapFunction
>   does a parallel (partitions) join between the model and the result of
>   the session windows, so you need some form of key that selects which
>   partition the elements go to. Does that make sense?
>
> If not, try to set it to parallelism 1 explicitly.
>
> Greetings, Stephan
>
> ---
>
> A global state that all can access read-only is doable via
>   broadcast().
>
> A global state that is available to all for read and update is
>   currently not available. Consistent operations on that would be quite
>   costly, require some form of distributed communication/consensus.
>
> Instead, I would encourage you to go with the following:
>
> 1) If you can partition the state, use a keyBy().mapWithState() - That
>   localizes state operations and makes it very fast.
>
> 2) If your state is not organized by key, your state is probably very
>   small, and you may be able to use a non-parallel operation.
>
> 3) If some operation updates the state and another one accesses it,
>   you can often implement that with iterations and a CoFlatMapFunction
>   (one side is the original input, the other the feedback input).
>
> All approaches in the end localize state access and modifications,
>   which is a good pattern to follow, if possible.
>
> Greetings, Stephan