# Class State get loss between function calls in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have this class:

```
case class IDADiscretizer(
  nAttrs: Int,
  nBins: Int = 5,
  s: Int = 5) extends Serializable {

  private[this] val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  private[this] val V = Vector.tabulate(nAttrs)(i => new IntervalHeapWrapper(nBins, i))
  private[this] val randomReservoir = SamplingUtils.reservoirSample((1 to s).toList.iterator, 1)

  def updateSamples(v: LabeledVector): Vector[IntervalHeapWrapper] = {
    val attrs = v.vector.map(_._2)
    val label = v.label
    // TODO: Check for missing values
    attrs
      .zipWithIndex
      .foreach {
        case (attr, i) =>
          if (V(i).getNbSamples < s) {
            V(i) insertValue attr // insert
          } else {
            if (randomReservoir(0) <= s / (i + 1)) {
              //val randVal = Random nextInt s
              //V(i) replace (randVal, attr)
              V(i) insertValue attr
            }
          }
      }
    V
  }

  /**
   * Return the cutpoints for the discretization
   *
   */
  def cutPoints: Vector[Vector[Double]] = V map (_.getBoundaries.toVector)

  def discretize(data: DataSet[LabeledVector]): (DataSet[Vector[IntervalHeapWrapper]], Vector[Vector[Double]]) = {
    val r = data map (x => updateSamples(x))
    val c = cutPoints

    (r, c)
  }
}
```

Using flink, I would like to get the cutpoints after the call of `discretize`, but it seems the information stored in `V` get loss. Do I have to use  `Broadcast` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015086/share-state-among-operators-in-flink)? is there a better way to access the state of class?

I've tried to call `cutpoints` in two ways, one with is:

```
def discretize(data: DataSet[LabeledVector]) = data map (x => updateSamples(x))
```

Then, called from outside:

```
val a = IDADiscretizer(nAttrs = 4)
val r = a.discretize(dataSet)
r.print
val cuts = a.cutPoints
```

Here, cuts is empty so I tried to compute the discretization as well as the cutpoints inside `discretize`:

```
def discretize(data: DataSet[LabeledVector]) = {
    val r = data map (x => updateSamples(x))
    val c = cutPoints

    (r, c)
  }
```

And use it like this:

```
val a = IDADiscretizer(nAttrs = 4)
val (d, c) = a.discretize(dataSet)
c foreach println
```

But the same happends.

Finally, I've also tried to make `V` completely public:

```
val V = Vector.tabulate(nAttrs)(i => new IntervalHeapWrapper(nBins, i))
```

Still empty

What am I doing wrong?

Related questions:

- [Keep keyed state across multiple transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968858/keep-keyed-state-across-multiple-transformations)
- [Flink State backend keys atomicy and distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738021/flink-state-backend-keys-atomicy-and-distribution)
- [Flink: does state access across stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806621/flink-does-state-access-across-stream)
- [Flink: Sharing state in CoFlatMapFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755697/flink-sharing-state-in-coflatmapfunction?rq=1)

### Answer

Thanks to @TillRohrmann what I finally did was:

```
private[this] def computeCutPoints(x: LabeledVector) = {
    val attrs = x.vector.map(_._2)
    val label = x.label
    attrs
      .zipWithIndex
      .foldLeft(V) {
        case (iv, (v, i)) =>
          iv(i) insertValue v
          iv
      }
  }

  /**
   * Return the cutpoints for the discretization
   *
   */
  def cutPoints(data: DataSet[LabeledVector]): Seq[Seq[Double]] =
    data.map(computeCutPoints _)
      .collect
      .last.map(_.getBoundaries.toVector)

  def discretize(data: DataSet[LabeledVector]): DataSet[LabeledVector] =
data.map(updateSamples _)
```

And then use it like this:

```
val a = IDADiscretizer(nAttrs = 4)
val d = a.discretize(dataSet)
val cuts = a.cutPoints(dataSet)
d.print
cuts foreach println
```

I do not know if it is the best way, but at least is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Flink works is that the user defines operators/user defined functions which operate on input data coming from a source function. In order to execute a program the user code is sent to the Flink cluster where it is executed. The results of the computation has to be output to some storage system via a sink function.

Due to this, it is not possible to mix local and distributed computations easily as you are trying with your solution. What `discretize` does is to define a `map` operator which transforms the input `DataSet` `data`. This operation will be executed once you call `ExecutionEnvironment#execute` or `DataSet#print`, for example. Now the user code and the definition for `IDADiscretizer` is sent to the cluster where they are instantiated. Flink will update the values in an instance of `IDADiscretizer` which is not the same instance as the one you have on the client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what is the best approach then? Should I use broadcasts? or try to chain the transformations?

Comment: The thing you should do is to do the `cutPoints` calculation on the cluster and write the result to a sink or retrieve it via `collect`. If you have all the information for `V` available after running `discretize` then you should directly call `cutPoints` in the same function. If you need to aggregate the results of `discretize` then you have to add a grouping operation and then apply `cutPoints` in the grouping function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it.

Comment: By _If you have all the information for V available after running discretize then you should directly call cutPoints in the same function_ you mean this?  `val d = data.map(updateSamples(_)); val c = cutPoints` This way I still get an empty result.

Comment: It should happen within the map function on the `DataSet` and then be then result in a `DataSet<CutPointsResult>`.